# Binary Search Tree: How/if to handle unlucky insertion orders?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm brushing up on fundamental algorithms and data structures.

A typical binary search tree insertion algorithm looks something like:

```
insert(newValue)
    if newValue is less than node.value:
        if lesser subtree exists:
            insert into lesser subtree
        otherwise:
            lesser subtree = new tree with newValue
    if newValue is greater than node.value
        if greater subtree exists:
            insert into greater subtree
        otherwise:
            greater subtree = new tree with newValue
```

With an unlucky insertion order, you can get a tree that is identical to a list:

```
insert(1)
insert(2)
insert(3)
```

Produces:

```
1
 \ 
  2
   \
    3
```

With a tree that is actually a list, searching will of course take linear time.

Is expected for a binary search tree implementation? Or would you expect the insertion function to do some sort of rebalancing?

Comment: Hi Nick, yes, you would typically have a rebalancing step, to avoid the very scenario you pointed out above.  I think most data structure textbooks should cover this; if not, a search on SO or Google would likely reveal a good starting point for an algorithm to rebalance.

Comment: did you google and found nothing?

Comment: You want a [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Answer (score 0):

You have two kind of binary search trees. First one that you have, in worst case it will take Linear time to insert and delete and this happends when you insert things in `Increasing` or `decreasing` order.

However this is simple binarysearch tree.

There  are also `RedBlack Binary search` trees or sometimes called 2-3 binary search tree because in every node you can have two values. This means that from every node you have red link or black link to other node.These are called balanced search tree because number of black edges are equal in each path(from source to depth). Here Binary search tree grows from downside but RedBlack search tree pops up a value when it's node is full(that's interesting).

**Search and insert:** This algorithm is a bit complex but it's complexity for insert and search is always `~logN`.

**Max height** Max height of this tree is between `log3N` and `logN`:

Here is a trace how it works:
[image]

Comment: also, look into AVL trees, which are another form of height-balanced binary search tree

Comment: @information_interchange yes there are many but what gives the best complexity matters a lot :)

Comment: Red-Black trees are analogous to 2-3-4 trees. One may want to mention AA trees, which are analogous to 2-3 trees, and their implementation are easier than RB-trees. AA trees are definitely recommended, when someone wants to write a balanced tree implementation for the first time. The other recommendation would be AVL-trees.

Comment: @geza You can't gain efficiency by using simple things! AVL trees are same as RedBlackTree but is there complexity of every operation is same?,Look how they rotate links!. Apart from this many operations whcih RB-trees suport AVL don't. If you can implement RB trees then you can implment AVL but not inverse of this :)

Comment: @LuaiGhunim: don't mix these trees, please. AVL and RB trees are both balanced trees, and that's the only common thing. They use different algorithms for insert/delete. In my opinion, RB trees are one of the most difficult trees to implement. AA trees are much simpler. And, despite AA trees are simpler, they have similar performance to RB trees. That's why I recommended, that for someone, who implements balanced trees for the first time, one should implement AA/AVL trees first. Not RB trees, for which remove is a nightmare.